hooks inside functions that are imported
So i know i can import/export a function. However, if i try to useState inside of the imported function it throws an error. Help me to understand how these work in react functional components.
Mainpage.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ExampleFunction from './exampleFunction'

const Example = () => {

    ExampleFunction();    

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={ExampleFunction}>Click<Button>
        <>
    )
};

ExampleFunction:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const [Data, setData] = useState('replace with test');

const ExampleFunction = () => {
    setData('test');
}

export default ExampleFunction;


The issue in this code is that you're trying to use the useState hook outside of a functional component. In React, hooks can only be used inside functional components. So, you need to move the useState declaration inside the ExampleFunction component for it to work correctly.

Hooks don’t just need to be used inside of functional components. They can also be used in custom hooks, which might be what OP is after here.
